# How do I make a java action perform smoother?

Tags: java, graphics, timer, refresh

I have created a simple program that fills a meter by how many times you press a button, eventually resulting into a "Mash the button to win" style game. I have it set up where every time the spacebar is pressed, the meter fills by 10/440, and if you reach the maximum, 440, you win. The issue I am having is how to make the increments added smoother, and less abrupt; as if you are pumping a bike tire up: continuous, less incrememntal. 
Here is the problematic code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.*;               
import java.util.*;                             
import static java.lang.System.*;
import static java.lang.Math.*;
import java.awt.*;                              
import java.awt.event.*;                                
import java.io.*;   //for files                     
public class MyClicker
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new Clicker();  //Make a window
    }

}
class Clicker extends Frame   implements KeyListener, MouseListener
{
    // global variables
    private final static int SCHEIGHT=768,SCWIDTH=1024;
    // direction constants

    final static int N = 0,NE = 1,E = 2,SE = 3, S = 4, SW = 5, W = 6, NW =7,STILL = 8;
    // movement change constants
    final  int X = 0,Y = 1,Z = 2;
    final int TITLE = 30, STATUS = 40;
    final static int size = 2;
    Image myPic;

    private boolean gameNotOver = true;
    private boolean keyPressed = false;
    private Image myScreen;
    private int whichScreen;
    private int timePassed;
    private int numScreen;
    private int maxAmt=450;
    private int timer;
    private int amt;

    public Clicker()
    {       
        setSize(SCWIDTH,SCHEIGHT);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
              {
                  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
                    {
                      System.exit(0);
                    }
               });
       timer = -1;
       this.setVisible(true);
       out.println(amt);
       this.addKeyListener(this);
       gameLoop();
    }
public void gameLoop()
{   
    do   
     {
        if (keyPressed)
           {
             amt = amt + 50;
             out.println(keyPressed + " " +gameNotOver+" "+ "Time "+timer);
             this.repaint();
             keyPressed = false;
           }
        if(amt >= 400)
            gameNotOver = false;
        pause(1000);
        timer++;
        this.setVisible(true);
        //this.repaint();
        pause(0);
        if(amt > maxAmt - 10)   
            amt = maxAmt - 10;
     }
   while (gameNotOver);

   if(!gameNotOver)
    {
        pause(5000);
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
public int getAmt()
{
    return amt;
}
public void paint(Graphics pen)
 {    
        if(whichScreen==0)
            {
                pen.drawImage(myPic,100,200,506,279,this);   //Draws the image
                pen.setFont(new Font("Timesroman", Font.ITALIC, 50));
                pen.drawString("Welcome to the Clicker Test", 200, 75);
                pen.setFont(new Font("Timesroman", Font.ITALIC, 40));
                pen.drawString("Created by Cody Coulter",150,150);
                pen.setFont(new Font("Timesroman", Font.ITALIC, 25));
                pause(200); // 2000 final           
                whichScreen++;
                doubleBuffer(pen);
            }
        else
            {
                myScreen =createImage(getSize().width,getSize().height);
                Graphics o = myScreen.getGraphics();
                doubleBuffer(o);
                pen.drawImage(myScreen,0,0,this);
            }
 }   
public void doubleBuffer(Graphics pen)  // Draws the window
 {     
          pause (500);
          numScreen++;
          if (numScreen > 0)          
               {      
                    setBounds(0,0,SCWIDTH,SCHEIGHT);
                    Color HPRed = new Color(213, 0, 0);
                    pen.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    setTitle("Clicker Test  -- Cody Coulter."+
                             "To click, press the space bar");
                    pen.setFont(new Font("Timesroman",Font.PLAIN,48));
                    pen.drawString("Clicker Test ",350,75);
                    pen.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman",Font.BOLD,33));
                    pen.fillRect((SCWIDTH/4), (SCHEIGHT/3), 50, maxAmt);
                    pen.drawString(""+timer, 350, 150);

                    pen.setColor(HPRed);
                    pen.fillRect((SCWIDTH/4)+5, (SCHEIGHT/3)+5, 40, amt);


                    if(!gameNotOver)
                     {
                        if(amt >= maxAmt-10)
                        {
                            pen.setColor(HPRed);
                            pen.fillRect(SCWIDTH/4-75, SCHEIGHT/3, SCWIDTH/2+150, SCHEIGHT/3-60);
                            pen.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                            pen.fillRect(SCWIDTH/4-65, SCHEIGHT/3+10, SCWIDTH/2+130, SCHEIGHT/3-80);
                            pen.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                            pen.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 40));
                            pen.drawString("You got it!", SCWIDTH/2-290, SCHEIGHT/2-20);
                        }
                     }
                    this.repaint();
               }
}    
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    keyPressed = true;
    setTitle(""+ KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));  
    System.out.println("hit + "+ KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode())+ " " + keyPressed);
    switch(e.getKeyCode())
       {
          case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE: if(amt < maxAmt - 10)
                                      amt= amt + 10;
                                  break; 
          case KeyEvent.VK_A: if(amt < maxAmt - 10)
                                      amt = amt + 10;
                                  break;
       }
}
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent m)
{
}   
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent m)
{
}   
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent m)
{
}   
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent m)
{
}   
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent m)
{
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{
}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
{
}

public void update(Graphics G)
{
      paint(G);
}       
public static void pause (long r)
{
    try
       {
           Thread.sleep(r);
       }
    catch (Exception e) 
       {
           out.println(" sleep error " + e);
        }          
}
}  //end class
```

And here is the entirely up to date code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.*;               
import java.util.*;                             
import static java.lang.System.*;
import static java.lang.Math.*;
import java.awt.*;                              
import java.awt.event.*;                                
import java.io.*;   //for files

public class MyClicker
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new Clicker();  //Make a window
    }

}
class Clicker extends Frame   implements KeyListener, MouseListener
{
    // global variables
    private final static int SCHEIGHT=768,SCWIDTH=1024;
    // direction constants

    final static int N = 0,NE = 1,E = 2,SE = 3, S = 4, SW = 5, W = 6, NW =7,STILL = 8;
    // movement change constants
    final  int X = 0,Y = 1,Z = 2;
    final int TITLE = 30, STATUS = 40;
    final static int size = 2;
    Image myPic;

    private boolean gameNotOver = true;
    private boolean keyPressed = false;
    private Image myScreen;
    private int whichScreen;
    private int timePassed;
    private int numScreen;
    private int maxAmt=450;
    private int dispAmt;
    private int actAmt;
    private double timer;

    public Clicker()
    {       
        setSize(SCWIDTH,SCHEIGHT);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
              {
                  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
                    {
                      System.exit(0);
                    }
               });
       timer = -1;
       this.setVisible(true);
       this.addKeyListener(this);
       gameLoop();
    }
public void gameLoop()
{   
    do   
     {
        if (keyPressed)
           {
             out.println(keyPressed + " " +gameNotOver+" "+ "Time "+timer);
             keyPressed = false;
           }
        if(dispAmt > maxAmt-10)
            dispAmt = maxAmt;
        if(actAmt >= maxAmt-10 || dispAmt >= maxAmt-10)
            gameNotOver = false;
        if(dispAmt < actAmt)
            dispAmt++;
        timer++;
        this.setVisible(true);
//          this.repaint();
//          pause(0);
//          if(actAmt > maxAmt - 10 || dispAmt > maxAmt - 10)   
//              actAmt = maxAmt - 10;

        this.repaint();
     }
   while (gameNotOver);

   if(!gameNotOver)
    {
        pause(5000);
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
public int getAmt()
{
    return actAmt;
}
public void paint(Graphics pen)
 {    
        if(whichScreen==0)
            {
                pen.drawImage(myPic,100,200,506,279,this);   //Draws the image
                pen.setFont(new Font("Timesroman", Font.ITALIC, 50));
                pen.drawString("Welcome to the Clicker Test", 200, 75);
                pen.setFont(new Font("Timesroman", Font.ITALIC, 40));
                pen.drawString("Created by Cody Coulter",150,150);
                pen.setFont(new Font("Timesroman", Font.ITALIC, 25));
                pause(200); // 2000 final           
                whichScreen++;
                doubleBuffer(pen);
            }
        else
            {
                myScreen =createImage(getSize().width,getSize().height);
                Graphics o = myScreen.getGraphics();
                doubleBuffer(o);
                pen.drawImage(myScreen,0,0,this);
            }
 }   
public void doubleBuffer(Graphics pen)  // Draws the window
 {     
          numScreen++;
          if (numScreen > 0)          
               {      
                    setBounds(0,0,SCWIDTH,SCHEIGHT);
                    Color HPRed = new Color(213, 0, 0);
                    pen.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    setTitle("Clicker Test  -- Cody Coulter."+
                             "To click, press the space bar");
                    pen.setFont(new Font("Timesroman",Font.PLAIN,48));
                    pen.drawString("Clicker Test ",350,75);
                    pen.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman",Font.BOLD,33));
                    pen.fillRect((SCWIDTH/4), (SCHEIGHT/3), 50, maxAmt);
                    pen.drawString(""+timer/1000, 350, 150);
                    pen.drawString(""+dispAmt+"  /  "+actAmt, 350, 200);

                    pen.setColor(HPRed);
                    pen.fillRect((SCWIDTH/4)+5, (SCHEIGHT/3)+5, 40, dispAmt);


                    if(!gameNotOver)
                     {
                        if(actAmt >= maxAmt-10)
                        {
                            pen.setColor(HPRed);
                            pen.fillRect(SCWIDTH/4-75, SCHEIGHT/3, SCWIDTH/2+150, SCHEIGHT/3-60);
                            pen.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                            pen.fillRect(SCWIDTH/4-65, SCHEIGHT/3+10, SCWIDTH/2+130, SCHEIGHT/3-80);
                            pen.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                            pen.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 40));
                            pen.drawString("You got it!", SCWIDTH/2-290, SCHEIGHT/2-20);
                        }
                     }
                    this.repaint();
               }
}    
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    keyPressed = true;
    setTitle(""+ KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));  
    System.out.println("hit + "+ KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode())+ " " + keyPressed);
    switch(e.getKeyCode())
       {
          case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:actAmt = actAmt+10;
                                  break; 
          case KeyEvent.VK_A: actAmt = actAmt+10;
                                  break;
       }
    this.repaint();
}
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent m)
{
}   
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent m)
{
}   
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent m)
{
}   
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent m)
{
}   
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent m)
{
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{
}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
{
}

public void update(Graphics G)
{
      paint(G);
}       
public static void pause (long r)
{
    try
       {
           Thread.sleep(r);
       }
    catch (Exception e) 
       {
           out.println(" sleep error " + e);
        }          
}
}  //end class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Get rid of pause(1000) you can maybe make it pause(10) or something around that.
- Call this.repaint() every time in your loop (outside of the if statement).
- Split amt into two variables: the actual amount, and the displayed amount.  Only draw the displayed amount, and have key presses only increase the actual amount.
- Each frame, if displayed amount is less than actual amount increase it by 1.

Updated...

- Remove pause(500) from the double buffer routine, and pause(200) from paint.  In general, don't pause unless you need to do "nothing".  Games never do "nothing", they almost always have a core loop that's at least rendering.

Comment: This helps immensely. To clarify your third point, you are saying I should make a private int for each dispAmt, and actAmt? And in doing so, use
    pen.fillRect((SCWIDTH/4)+5, (SCHEIGHT/3)+5, 40, dispAmt);
if this is not correct, sorry, just kind of new to programming, so I'm trying to understand all purposes still

Thank you, again

Comment: Yes. It sounds like you got it.  You would no longer have 'amt' and would have 'dispAmt', and 'actAmt'.  Good luck!

Comment: After rereading your point, I figured it out, and felt pretty idiotic for not understanding prior... But, now that I have taken out the pause, and the increments have stabilized, and the meter functions exactly how I intended. Thank you for the help, but the initial inquiry hasn't really been solved. Right now, my program increases exactly how I want it to, but each time I press the spacebar in order to increase the meter, it only responds approximately every .75 seconds. I want it to be able to instantly respond, as if it were continuous rather than discrete. If not possible thank you anyways

Comment: If you move this.repaint() to to end of your keypressed handler, it will update instantly.  Also get rid of the pause(500) from your double buffer routine.

Comment: by keypressed handler, you're referring to the keyPressed(KeyEvent e) method? And if so, you're saying I insert repaint after Switch, or within each case? I guess the at the bottom of the method would be best, if it reads Any key pressed within the switch/case 'library,' if you will.

Comment: Yes, right before the method returns you could call repaint and the screen would update immediately.  Note that's not normally how we do it for video games.  We usually try to have a consistent "draw" loop that repaints regardless of input, so animations and whatnot can still run.  Can you post your most recent code?

Comment: And because of a basic curiosity in general video game programming, when you alluded to a draw loop, are you referring to a simple do/while this.repaint()? And another basic question is how would i be able to source to this file when creating a new one? As in making a game, and implimenting this meter as a stamina, etc. without copy/pasting? i.e. (may be incorrect format) Object clicker = new Clicker(); or even a simple clicker() in the new main?

Comment: In your case gameLoop() would be the "draw loop" I was talking about.  I just meant that usually drawing is done regardless of input, so although putting repaint() your keyPressed method would give "instant" feedback, that's not normally where it would go.  Having it in gameLoop() should be fine after you've removed all the pauses.

Comment: As for making this a component of a bigger project, there's lot's of ways to do that, so you should really just try and see what works for you.  If i was plugging this into a "new" project, I'd change the class to not extend Frame (since the new one will have it's own window already).  Then in the paint() call for the new class, call the paint() method for this component, and pass it the Graphics that was passed to you.  You might have to do something similar to handle the key press events.

Comment: Thank you very much, you have helped me immensely. I have the program as is, exactly how I imagined it to be from the start. In a completely unrelated, and possible unanswerable question, as there is no right answer, with me being in my last bit of high school, and wanting to pursue a career in the programming field, do you have any suggestions on how to help better my own understanding of coding, syntax, etc. for this to be a possibility? Everyone I have discussed this with have just said with a cold attitude, "Get a book, go away." If you don't feel you want to answer, all is good. Thank you

Comment: I started (at age 7 when programming books were sparse) with a lot of trial and error.  Don't be afraid to just try stuff, and I mean that at a really low level, like "what happens if I pass this function true, instead of false like I usually do?"  I ended up making a lot of crap, but also learned a lot about how to put a program together.  Later (after the internet and opensource) I switched to learning by looking at other people's code.  I feel learning by example is still the best way, just look out for bad examples too, and down't be afraid to tweak what you  find.

Comment: Oreilly books tend to be good, most others tend to suck (there are exceptions in both cases).  I have lots of books, but generally use the internet for info instead.  Stack Overflow is a great resource for detailed information when you're already 99% of the way there and can't find a bug.  Avoid it for "high level" problems and general questions since that's not really what it's for. Google searches have Stack Overflow as at least one of the top 10 hits. If you're interested in game programming (which is what I do), check out Unity. It's free and has tons of sample code on their website.

Comment: p.s. Although it was more of a conversation than an answer, you can mark my answer as "correct" so it doesn't appear "unresolved" (and I get a little credit too).

Comment: (I tried to move this to chat for arbitrary information "spamming" the through comments, but am just 2 shy of being able to do so) I can't thank you enough. Honestly, this site has helped me in this endeavor exponentially more than any other source I have encountered. I learn best through example, and am attempting to learn the way you mentioned. I am 17, currently, and started, as I said, in August 2013 at 16. I feel as if my late start makes me just too far behind. I have 1 more year until I graduate; do you know any sources I need to pursue, or if I need to fret over other languages?

Comment: People say "language doesn't matter, just learn with what you have access to". While that's true for beginner programmers, when you're talking about careers, the languages you know are the primary factor in what jobs you can apply for. For the best language, look into the industry you're interested in, and what tech you want to work on, and see what languages they use. Web servers (in any industry) use a lot of Java and C#. NodeJS is also getting popular. For web sites (front end) learn javascript. Games can be anything but big ones are still mostly C++. FWIW Minecraft was written in Java.

Comment: So professionally, in the formal business world at least, C# is a good place to start, as well as java/JavaScript? And games, primarily use C++ or java? (disregarding python, etc. just broad spectrum) And by NodeJS you mean NodeJavaScript? I'm not too familiar with acronyms other than JS or C# lol. Again, you have done much more than I could have ever asked for! Thank you so much, I can't thank you enough. You have immensely helped by answering questions always dodged by others (as you alluded to with the language issue)

Comment: There's a huge diversity for games, but C++ is still the most common for PC games, especially bigger ones.  I don't really like C++ because it's too low level.  But when performance is critical, it's hard to compete with.  Java is quite rare for game clients (the part running on your PC with graphics and all), which is what made Minecraft interesting.  For games that have a server component (multiplayer, high scores, cloud saves), Java is popular, but there still a lot of diversity there too.  NodeJS is a javascript based server.

Comment: Again, I can't thank you enough. You have helped so much more than I expected. I have been thinking about starting with C++ or C#, seeing as my programs primarily consist of basic "games" as in the one discussed in this post. I make basic prorams like Blackjack, etc. I want to get into the appealing and efficient programs, such as launchers, websites, game UI, etc. I think it will be best if I do work with both. Would you suggest this course of action? The biggest issue I run into is the lack of creativity for programs. "Programmer's Block" if you will.

Comment: I'd only go with C++ if you want to work at a big game company like EA or Blizzard on big games. If you want to do indie games, go with Unity, you'll get a lot higher quality product with a lot less effort.  Unity lets you use javascript or C#.  So even from a learning perspective, you'll gain skills that apply outside of games too.